# Fail to Send Email via Python Due to Missing Local Name

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am facing below error while trying to send email via Python and would like to get some help.

```
  File "test.py", line 36, in <module>
    send_mail.mailer(x)
  File "D:\Desktop\test\mailer_func.py", line 116, in mailer
    server.sendmail(SENDER, toaddrs, msg_body)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 888, in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'Transaction failed: Missing local name')
```

Comment: Most likely a bad mail address, but hard so say for sure without any details to reproduce.

Comment: what information do you need?

Comment: Everything required to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example